# I recording video to FMS want to improve video quality.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-media-server

I recording video to FMS dvr 
I want to improve quality of video sending to FMS. 
How could I do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code you are using to capture video. For example, we don't know how/if you are using the Camera.setMode() and Camera.setQuality() methods. Those two and the web cam's supported resolutions are what determine the image quality.

Comment: public function publishCamera():void{
   cam = Camera.getCamera();
   
   mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
   mic.gain = 50;
   vid = new Video(550, 350);
   vid.x = 1.5;
   vid.y = 1;
   vid.smoothing = true;
   vid.attachCamera(cam);
   addChild(vid);
   recorder.record_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleRecordClicked);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the camera, you can configure it with the and [setMode()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode%28%29) and [setQuality()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setQuality%28%29) methods. The documentation for these methods is worth reading.

First, I suggest you play with the `setMode()` method. This sets the capture resolution of the camera. The default resolution is 160x120.

For a better quality picture, you want to specify a capture resolution that is the same or similar to the dimensions that you will apply to the `Video` object.  I would also suggest using values in a 4:3 ratio, like 480x360:

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
camera.setMode(480,360,24); // 480x360 resolution at 24 fps
var video:Video = new Video(480,360);
video.attachCamera(camera);
```

Play with the dimensions, but try to keep them in 4:3 ratio for best results. This will be a big improvement, you might even stop here.

Optionally, you can fine tune the streaming experience with the `setQuality()` method. This lets you specify a preference for bandwidth use or picture quality. For highest quality you could do:

```
camera.setQuality(0,100); // please read the docs before doing this :)
```

Be aware that as you increase the capture resolution and the quality, you also increase the file size/bandwidth of your video. You will find the right balance!

Comment: Thank you Sir,
I will try this and let you know the result.